# Javascript Swap image, image inst resolving

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, dhtml, swap

I have a site setup were Im swapping the image inside a div when a thumbnail is hovered over, and the source is here: `http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/thumbnailviewer2.js`

Im running into an issue where I run the mouse cursor over the thumbnail and it shows the loading spinner and just sits there, I am pretty sure its down to the url

NOTIMAGE-http://localhost/index.php?main_page=popup_image&pID=1&pic=0&products_image=images/test_product_01.jpg-NOTIMAGE`

I do know its loading it but I can not tell why it wont get the image. I do see that there is an error or warning "Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/html."

Does anyone have an idea of what may be going wrong? Here is a snip of the source.

```
<a href="http://localhost/index.php?main_page=popup_image&amp;pID=1&pic=0&products_image=images/test_product_01.jpg" target="_blank" rel="enlargeimage" rev="targetdiv:mainSlider,link:http://localhost/index.php?main_page=popup_image&amp;pID=1"><img src="images/test_product_01.jpg" alt="Test Product" title=" Test Product " width="35" height="35" /><br /><span class="imgLinkAdditional"></span></a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message:

> Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/html.

Should be a dead give away. Your `index.php?...products_image=images/test_product_01.jpg` is sending back, presumably, a blog of data that should have an `image/jpeg` MIME type but, and this is a big but, the server is saying

```
Content-type: text/html
```

in the headers. So, the browser thinks you're trying to put `text/html` data in an `<img>` and it rightly refuses.

The solution is to ensure that your PHP script sets the `Content-type` header to `image/jpeg` when it is sending back the `test_product_01.jpg` image.